# Trying to use a custom script to show/hide element [WP]

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to hide an element by javascript, but it just won't work.

This is the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null @ custom_script.js?ver=1.0:1`

**custom_script.js:** this is everything in the file

```
document.getElementById("test123").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

And I'm sure that the element got the `#test123` as you can see in the following image:
[image]

Hope someone knows this problem! I've already tried many ways.
Using Jquery gave me the error that `$` isn't a function.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running the script before the document has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script must be loaded after the element, in this case `#test123` has been loaded.

```
<div id="test123"></div>
<script src="custom_script.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, I've tried this `(function(funcName, baseObj) {
//content here
})("docReady", window);` with no success..

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thats what I mean by being loaded after the actual element.